# How can I completely uninstall btsync from an ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, bittorrent-sync

I installed btsync in Ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install btsync
```

Then there was something wrong and I needed to do a fresh install, so I removed it with

```
sudo apt-get purge btsync
```

However I still noticed that the user btsync was not removed from the system. 
Furthermore, after I reinstalled btsync with apt-get it was still recognizing an old synced folder as having a former btsync configuration to it and the orignial problem of not having permissions to write to folder persisted. I really would like to start fresh with btsync but without reinstalling ubuntu! Is this possible?

Comment: I think it is more for superuser question.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt-get -y remove --purge btsync btsync-common`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks